# Is there a way to identify a hidden slide in a google presentation using google apps script?

Tags: c#, google-apps-script, google-api-dotnet-client, google-slides-api

In C#, the code is `Slides[].SlideShowTransition.Hidden`. Can anyone tell me the google script alternative for the same?

Comment: Where are you finding the reference for `SlideShowTransition`? It's not listed in the [reference](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/slides/v1/csharp/latest/annotated.html)

Answer (score 1):

After doing some research I see that `SlideShowTransition` is a property of the VBA Office API for Microsoft Powerpoint.

Unfortunately, there is currently no method that exists in the Slides API, nor in Apps Script, that allows the viewing, editing or changing of transitions between slides in this manner.

I would suggest that if you want to see the implementation of this feature, you can head to Google's Issue Tracker and submit a feature request for this so it is made aware that users are wanting a feature like this. You can submit a Feature Request with the correct Component [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191598&template=823918).